# Conditional validation not working for anonymous Knockout validation rule

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have following attributes in my viewmodel which use knockout validation,one of them is custom validation to check password match.

```
model.Password = ko.observable()
                  .extend({ required: { message: "Password is required.", 
                        params: true,
                        onlyIf: function () { return model.IsCredentialsRequired(); }}
                    });


model.ConfirmPassword = ko.observable().
                        extend({ validation: { validator: mustEqual,
                        message: 'Passwords do not match.',
                        params: model.Password,               
                        onlyIf: function () { return model.IsCredentialsRequired(); } }
                    });
```

code for custom validation function

```
var mustEqual = function (val, other) {
                return val == other();
            };
```

I found that `OnlyIf` condition is working fine for `model.Password` depending on  `model.IsCredentialsRequired()` but its not working for `model.ConfirmPassword`,Can somebody help me why this is happening?Is there any another way by which i can use conditional validation for custom rules?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I still try to understand why your code is not working. Is model.IsCredentialsRequired a subscribable (observable or computed)?

Comment: right,model.IsCredentialsRequired is computed

Answer (score 18, accepted):

knockout-validation does currently not support 'onlyIf' for anonymous rules. But it is supported for custom rules. Therefore you can create a custom rule and use onlyIf with that:

```
ko.validation.rules['confirmPasswordMatches'] = {
    validator: function (val, params) {
        var otherValue = params;
        return val === ko.validation.utils.getValue(otherValue);
    },
    message: 'Passwords do not match.',
};
ko.validation.registerExtenders();

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.IsCredentialsRequired = ko.observable(true);

    self.Password = ko.observable()
        .extend({
            required: {
                message: "Password is required.",
                params: true,
                onlyIf: self.IsCredentialsRequired
            }
    });

    self.ConfirmPassword = ko.observable().
    extend({
            confirmPasswordMatches: {
            params: self.Password,
            onlyIf: self.IsCredentialsRequired
        }
    });

}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/delixfe/mFAEx/

Comment: this worked,but what if i want a custom rule,i want answer in that case too

Comment: I have updated the answer. In short: knockout-validation does not support onlyIf for anonymous rules. But it does for custom ones.