# Make ko validation only validate visible items

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have items dispersed within my view that are visible based on dates, drop down selections and the like. I would like to use ko validation because its nice to put validation logic in my model and not have to use a stupid form like you would with jquery validation.

The bonus I am seeing with jquery validation is that it only validates visible items even if they have the required class. Is there anyway to get this functionality from ko validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your knockout model I guess you should have a flag for visibility. You can use `onlyIf` option based on the flag. Something like:

```
self.IsFieldVisible = ko.observable(true); //Or False
self.FieldToValidate= ko.observable().extend({
  required: {
    onlyIf: function () { 
      return self.IsFieldVisible();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: and what if I need to hide another type of validation messages (for example, checking is it a number or not)?

Comment: You can use `onlyIf` with any validation type, even custom validations. Have a look this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601463/conditional-validation-not-working-for-anonymous-knockout-validation-rule) to see how it works with custom validation